# WFFM reports showing duplicate records in excel file

Tags: wffm

I have created WFFM form and I am able to submit the form as well. But when I see the form report by downloading in Excel format, I am getting duplicate records. For each entry in WFFM form, I am getting it two times in excel. Is anybody know why this is happening?

Answer (score 1):

This was an issue with Sitecore and that got fixed in Sitecore Web Forms for Marketers 8.1 rev. 160304 (Update-2)

If you are using the old version - Please raise a ticket to Sitecore support team to provide the Patch for this.

Below are the details for the fixed issue

An issue had caused duplicate rows of submitted data to be written to the database table when using the combinedFormsDataProvider setting from the Sitecore.WFFM.Dependencies.config file in scaled environments. (88634)

For more details, Please find the Sitecore release note.

https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Web%20Forms%20For%20Marketers/Web%20Forms%20For%20Marketers%2081/Web%20Forms%20For%20Marketers%2081%20Update2/Release%20Notes

Hope this will answer your query